# Is it possible to pass a Django id inside an HTML element, to a jQuery function?

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

I am displaying a list of blog posts in a for loop, each has a comment form with send button underneath it. I need to let Django know which specific post has been clicked on so have added `{{post.id}}` to the button element's id. How do I then pass this information to jQuery? Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<button id="addComBtn{{post.id}}...>Send</button>

$('#addComBtn //post.id here').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Hi, you can change your selector like this : `$('button[id*=addComBtn]').click(function() { //you code })` .

Comment: Thank you Swati, I tried this, and I also tried `$('button[id*=addComBtn{{post.id}}]').click(function() {` and it still only allows me to update the first post in the loop

Comment: That event gets called or not ? Also how do you get `id` from button ?

Comment: I have given my button the data id attribute, `data-id="{{post.id}}"` This helps me return the correct id, but I have a problem now with my ajax response. For the first post in the loop, response correctly returns an object dictionary, but for all other posts it is returning the html for the entire document

Comment: Did you check if correct `id` value is getting passed to backend ? Sorry i have limited knowledge in django.

Comment: Yes, I am receiving the correct id, it is an ajax issue I have now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224531/discussion-between-swati-and-sgt-pepper85).

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you tried out?

Yes it is possible. This should be the solution

```html
<button id="addComBtn{{post.id}}...>Send</button>

$('#addComBtn{{ post.id }}').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Because first Django renders the page, with its own engine(meaning, it doesn't check anything else outside of `{%%}`s and `{{}}`s), then it sends to the client, and when it renders, it will replace that.

Comment: Thank you. I did try this out, but when I add `post.id` like this my button does not do anything

Comment: The problem is probably is in your jQuery script. Check the page source from browser and see if it's `$('#addComBtn<someid>')`, if it's like this then the problem is in your script not the Django.

Comment: If I do not include `post.id` my script works fine, but only for the first post in the loop

Comment: The source code shows each button has its correct id in place, for example `<button id="addComBtn34`